# How to echo elements of array in a callback for a forEach

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to `echo` the contents of an array of links. Tried to use this:

```
casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    links.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        echo(element);
    });
});
```

But get an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.echo(element)')
```

How to echo each link to the console?

Comment: I'm worried this is a trick question.

Comment: Where did you define the `echo` function? The error message and your code don't match.

Comment: Please consider that I'm a beginner in Javascript.  I'm running this from a virtual terminal.  `console.log` doesn't echo anything on the terminal.

Comment: Please edit your question to either change the code or the error message, because they don't match. There is no `this.echo(..)` in the code, but only `echo(...)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing this in a forEach loop results in undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445599/accessing-this-in-a-foreach-loop-results-in-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, it's "this.echo"; However, since "this" might change based on context, you'll want to save the parent context:

```
casper.then(function() {
    var self=this;
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    links.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        self.echo(element);
    });
});
```

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/1.1-beta2/modules/casper.html

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
echo(element);
```

with

```
console.log(element);
```