# PrimeNG Turbotable expand by default

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have a [PrimeNg turbotable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table) with row expansion feature.

How can I expand the rows by default.

**Here is my Code :**

**HTML**

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" dataKey="vin">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 2.25em"></th>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{col.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
                <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-down' : 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td [attr.colspan]="columns.length + 1">
            <div class="ui-g ui-fluid" style="font-size:16px;padding:20px">
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-3" style="text-align:center">
                    <img [attr.alt]="rowData.brand" src="assets/showcase/images/demo/car/{{rowData.brand}}.png">
                </div>
                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-9">
                    <div class="ui-g">
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <b>Vin:</b> {{rowData.vin}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <b>Vin:</b> {{rowData.color}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <b>Brand:</b> {{rowData.brand}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="ui-g-12">
                            <b>Color:</b> {{rowData.color}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**Ts**

```
export class TableRowExpansionDemo implements OnInit {

    cars: Car[];

    cols: any[];

    constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.cars = cars);

        this.cols = [
            { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin' },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year' },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand' },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color' }
        ];
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using **expandedRowKeys** attribute, but it is not working for me.

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Update: For Version >7.x**

Setting value to 1 won't work on version 7+ use boolean(true/false)

```
const thisRef = this;
 this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
   thisRef.expandedRows[car.vin] = true;
 });
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3y2hkn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**For Version <7.x**

> I tried using expandedRowKeys attribute

Yes you're right. So add `[expandedRowKeys]="expandedRows">` to `p-table` element :

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" dataKey="vin" [expandedRowKeys]="expandedRows">
```

and then, you just need to fill `expandedRows` object with `vin` values of the rows you want to expand (because `dataKey` is `vin`).

Because you want all rows to be expanded, you can fill it like that :

```
    const thisRef = this;
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      thisRef.expandedRows[car.vin] = 1;
    });
```

in order to have something like 
`expandedRows = {"dsad231ff": 1, "gwregre345": 1, ...}`

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pL56vzFcrTVg0j9QMgZi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks @Antikhippe. What is the use if 1 in the expandedRows = {"dsad231ff": 1, "gwregre345": 1, ...} ?

Comment: I guess it means that corresponding row will be expanded if 1, collapsed if not.

Comment: @Antikhippe why if we directly assign this.expandedRows[car.vin] = 1; is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly" ?

Comment: why you are assigning 'this' property to constant.                                 
 // const thisRef = this;
    this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
      this.expandedRows[car.vin] = 1;
    });

Comment: It's because *this* is undefined inside a forEach loop when using `strict mode` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445599/accessing-this-in-a-foreach-loop-results-in-undefined)

Comment: @Antikhippe I tried with same configuration but seems not working. Can you please help?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qccqg8

Comment: @VijayChauhan set to true not 1, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3y2hkn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Rishi0405 When I used `thisRef.expandedRows[car.vin] = false;` then I need to **click two times** to expand any row. Why? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: @AbhijeetGiram Expanded rows(expandedRows) is to expand particular rows initally, so set to true to the rows you want to expand, and you dont want to set to false for other rows.
But if you want to close the rows manually, then set the row to null, because from the code, primeNg doesnt care about the negative type(false), it is just true/null
so setting to null seems to work :)

Answer (score 3):

In the accepted answer, the **expandedRows** mapping to the turbo table **expandedRowKeys** is one way i.e. it can set the state of rows at the time of loading only.
If someone want to collapse or expand it after the table is loaded, you can directly edit the '**expandedRowKeys**' variable by passing the table reference from the html.

Define Your table with a reference variable **#dt**

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" dataKey="vin">
```

Edit your table body like this to get a on click function trigger

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
                <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-down' : 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
           <a >
              <span (click)="onItemClick(rowData, dt)">
                    {{rowData[col.field]}}    
              </span>
           </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

in your TS  file add the function as

```
onItemClick(rowData:any, dt:any) {
   if(dt.expandedRowKeys[rowData._id]){
     dt.expandedRowKeys[rowData._id] = 0;
   }
   else {
    dt.expandedRowKeys[rowData._id] = 1;
   }
}
```

This approach gives you more freedom in changing state of table on a trigger of event from outside of table and expanding or collapsing multiple rows at once.

Answer (score 3):

After hitting many solution i tried and found easiest way to resolve

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" dataKey="vin" [expandedRowKeys]="expandedRows">
```

Replace datakey value to your unique id key from list of objects fetched from service or http calls.

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="repaymentsList" dataKey="id" expandableRows="true" rowExpandMode="single" [responsive]="true">
```