# PrimeNG Turbotable all expand

Tags: angular, html, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I'm using primeng turbotable but unable to expand all the raws by default.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qccqg8

Already tried with below example but seems not working.

[PrimeNG Turbotable expand by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925945/primeng-turbotable-expand-by-default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace Your code inside foreach loop like this, it will expand all rows by default.

```
 this.cars.forEach(function(car) {
     thisRef.expandedRows[car.vin] = true;
 });
```