# this.draw is not a function and will not run code properly

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to complete a project for my webdev course for school. I've been staring at this for hours trying different things and cannot see where i've gone wrong. Any help here would be hot.

```
//Initial Setup
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;

//Variables
const mouse = {
  x: innerWidth / 2,
  y: innerHeight / 2
};

const colors = ['#2185C5', '#7ECEFD', '#FFF6E5', '#FF7F66'];

// Event Listeners
addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  mouse.x = event.clientX;
  mouse.y = event.clientY;
});

addEventListener('resize', () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth
  canvas.height = innerHeight

  init();
})

//Utility Functions
function randomIntFromRange(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function randomColor(colors) {
    return colors [Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

// Objects
function Particle(x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.radius = radius
    this.color = color;
    this.radians = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
    this.velocity = 0.05;
    this.distanceFromCenter = randomIntFromRange(50, 120);
    this.lastMouse = {x: x, y: y};

    this.update = () => {
        const lastPoint = {x: this.x, y: this.y};

        //move points over time
        this.radians += this.velocity;

        //Drag Effect
        this.lastMouse.x += (mouse.x - this.lastMouse.x) * 0.05;
        this.lastMouse.y += (mouse.y - this.lastMouse.y) * 0.05;

        //Circuler Motion
        this.x = this.lastMouse.x + Math.cos(this.radians) * this.distanceFromCenter;
        this.y = this.lastMouse.y + Math.sin(this.radians) * this.distanceFromCenter;

        this.draw(lastPoint);
    };
  }

  this.draw = lastPoint => {
    c.beginPath();
    c.strokestyle = this.color;
    c.lineWidth = this.radius; 
    c.moveTo(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    c.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
    c.stroke();
    c.closePath();
  }

// Implementation
let particles;
    function init() {
        particles = []

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const radius = (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
     particles.push(new Particle(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, radius, randomColor(colors)));
  }
}

// Animation Loop
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.fillstyle = 'rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)


    particles.forEach(particle => {
        particle.update();
   })
}

init();
animate();
```

I keep running into the error of..."Uncaught TypeError: this.draw is not a function." I have been wracking my brain trying to make this work. Can someone please put another set of eyes on this for some relief? Thank you!

This is my HTML for running the JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST</title>
<style type="text/css">
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="java/project.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing this in a forEach loop results in undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445599/accessing-this-in-a-foreach-loop-results-in-undefined)

Answer (score 2):

This may sound like a silly answer, but have you tried renaming this.draw function to just draw()? Seeing the this.draw() function, it looks like there is no reason for the 'this' in the functions name. And don't forget to change the this.draw(lastPoint) to just draw(lastPoint). I really hopes this helps. Your code is really beautiful!

Comment: Or alternately, you could move that `this.draw` _inside_ of the `Particle` constructor. Then it'll be a method of the particle, whereas right now it's a method of the global object.

Comment: This fixed the issue! Thank you! I've been staring at it too long to even pick up on that!

Comment: That is great news! Can you list your question as answered by me please? Sooo happy for you! I hate getting stuck like that...lol!

Answer (score 1):

In the `animate()` function your code has fallen in an infinite loop. check this with this chunk of code:

```
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.fillstyle = 'rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
    c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)


    particles.forEach(particle => {
        particle.update();
        console.log("run")
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this shows the same error in console as before.